# Elegent way creating random ndarray in a nested list

Tags: python, list, numpy, multidimensional-array, nested

I am curios whether there is more elegant way of creating random ndarray in a nested list

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(0)
nested_list_array=[[[np.random.rand(5,5,1,2),np.random.rand(5,5,1,2),np.random.rand(5,5,1,2)],
              [np.random.rand(5,5,1,2),np.random.rand(5,5,1,2),np.random.rand(5,5,1,2)]],
            [[np.random.rand ( 5, 5, 1, 2 ), np.random.rand ( 5, 5, 1, 2 ), np.random.rand ( 5, 5, 1, 2 )],
             [np.random.rand ( 5, 5, 1, 2 ), np.random.rand ( 5, 5, 1, 2 ), np.random.rand ( 5, 5, 1, 2 )]],
            [[np.random.rand ( 5, 5, 1, 2 ), np.random.rand ( 5, 5, 1, 2 ), np.random.rand ( 5, 5, 1, 2 )],
             [np.random.rand ( 5, 5, 1, 2 ), np.random.rand ( 5, 5, 1, 2 ), np.random.rand ( 5, 5, 1, 2 )]],
            [[np.random.rand ( 5, 5, 1, 2 ), np.random.rand ( 5, 5, 1, 2 ), np.random.rand ( 5, 5, 1, 2 )],
             [np.random.rand ( 5, 5, 1, 2 ), np.random.rand ( 5, 5, 1, 2 ), np.random.rand ( 5, 5, 1, 2 )]],
            [[np.random.rand ( 5, 5, 1, 2 ), np.random.rand ( 5, 5, 1, 2 ), np.random.rand ( 5, 5, 1, 2 )],
             [np.random.rand ( 5, 5, 1, 2 ), np.random.rand ( 5, 5, 1, 2 ), np.random.rand ( 5, 5, 1, 2 )]]]
```

Comment: Are you really creating an array of dimension 5x2x3x5x5x1x2 ? A 7-dimension array ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
result = [[[np.random.rand(5, 5, 1, 2) for _ in range(3)] for _ in range(2)] for _ in range(5)]
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you could do so with list comprehension, e.g.,

```
[[np.random.rand ( 5, 5, 1, 2 ) for _ in range(3)] for _ in range(5)]
```